# Gitlab CI .gitlab-ci.yml only test certain branches

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can i get Gitlab CI to only monitor two specific branches?

I have a very basic script so far:

```
master:
    script: "npm install; grunt"
```

is it something like:

```
master:
    script: "npm install; grunt"
    only:
       - master
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, You can see the an example [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.md)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone else has the dot in the branch name too.
Our branch is called "1.0", so we had to do

```
  only:
      - /1.0/
```